# Rails forms: implementing a user form that handles multiple virtual attributes stored in the same text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm looking for the 'right' rails way to have a form edit multiple virtual attributes that are saved inside a single text field.

Right now, we store 8 virtual attributes in a single text field, and store them as an easily-parsed string, something like: `"weekday=monday; repeat_weekly_for= 5; repeat_monthly_for=4; ..."`

Then (as detailed below) the form has a text_field for each virtual attribute, and the model has a getter and setter for each virtual attribute.

When we need an attribute value, or need to set an attribute value, we first use a regex to parse the string into a hash.

It works. The issue is that each time a user displays then updates the form, that same regex parser gets called 16 times (8 times to 'read' the 8 virtual attributes, and 8 times to 'write' each of the 8 virtual attributes).

Is there a way to implement a getter and setter for all 8 virtual attributes at once?

Specifics:

Currently, our form looks like:

```
= f.text_field :weekday  /first virtual attribute
= f.text_field :repeat_weekly_for  /second virtual attribute
= f.text_field :repeat_monthly_for  /third virtual attribute
...
```

and so we have getter and setter for each virtual attribute that looks the same:

```
def weekday
  self.schedule_to_hash['weekday'] # this gets done 8 times for 8 attributes
end
def weekday=(the_weekday)
  schedule_hash = self.schedule_to_hash  # this gets done 8 times for 8 attributes
  schedule_hash['weekday'] = the_weekday
  self.hash_to_schedule(schedule_hash) # this gets done 8 times for 8 attributes
end
```

Each getter and setter uses these two methods to convert between hash and string formats:

```
def schedule_to_hash()
  # takes string self.schedule, does regex to split into hash, returns the hash
end

def hash_to_schedule(some_hash)
  # put the hash into a string format compatible with the regex in schedule_to_hash()
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord has a method called serialize http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

You can use it like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :schedule, Hash

  def weekday
    schedule ||= {}
    schedule['weekday']
  end

  def weekday=(the_weekday)
    schedule ||= {}
    schedule['weekday'] = the_weekday
  end
end
```

Rails will do the serialization/deserialization for you when the object is saved/loaded.